# Растянуть layout по ширине экрана

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Таблица содержит несколько столбцов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо растянуть заголовок по ширине страницы в зависимости от экрана.
Можно ли это сделать, не создавая дополнительные лейауты для разных плотностей экранов?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TableForTimer"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/duration"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/end"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/gap"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Есть такое свойство `match_parent` и виджет `TableLayout` они решат вашу проблему

Comment: Мне необходимо, что бы расстояние между столбцами тоже изменялось

Comment: `TableLayout` для этого и придумали, чтобы таблицы рисовать, адаптируемые под разные экраны.

Comment: Я использую `TableLayout`. В тем `TableRow`, в котором хранятся 5 `TextVeiw`, которые должны адаптироваться под разные экраны и представляют собой столбцы. Однако при выставлении `match_parent` отступы между столбцами на различных экранах не меняются.

Comment: Вы бы верстку для начала прикрепили

Comment: В данный момент, все выглядит следующим образом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/duration"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/end"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>

            <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/gap"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_margin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_table"/>
</LinearLayout>
```